# HDD error: SMART Status command failed: scsi error medium or hardware error (serious)

Tags: usb-drive, scsi

After my PC won't start again (my first guess was the power switch to turn it on was dead), I removed the HDD to extract my data. When I set the HDD (a 640 GB WD) into an external case (USB 2.0), the drive simply won't mount. I am using Fedora 21.

Debug output:

**SmartControl**

```
smartctl 6.4 2015-06-04 r4109 [x86_64-linux-4.1.5-100.fc21.x86_64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-15, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Western Digital Caviar Green
Device Model:     WDC WD6400AACS-00G8B1
Serial Number:    WD-WCAUF3310323
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0014ee 101fa1ac5
Firmware Version: 05.04C05
User Capacity:    640,135,028,736 bytes [640 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 2.5, 3.0 Gb/s
Local Time is:    Tue Sep 15 15:43:46 2015 CEST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Status command failed: scsi error medium or hardware error (serious)
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
Warning: This result is based on an Attribute check.

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x84) Offline data collection activity
                    was suspended by an interrupting command from host.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (15600) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 181) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   5) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x303f) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   200   200   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   142   137   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       5883
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       1796
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   200   200   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   100   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   092   092   000    Old_age   Always       -       6180
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       1766
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       75
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       1796
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   121   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       26
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       1
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   200   200   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   200   200   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

**dmesg**

```
[ 6908.519756] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[ 6908.684848] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=1058, idProduct=1021
[ 6908.684865] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 6908.684867] usb 1-2: Product: Ext HDD 1021
[ 6908.684870] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: Western Digital
[ 6908.684872] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: 574341554633333130333233
[ 6908.685583] usb-storage 1-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 6908.687976] scsi host13: usb-storage 1-2:1.0
[ 6909.694176] scsi 13:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WD       Ext HDD 1021     2021 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
[ 6909.695222] sd 13:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg4 type 0
[ 6909.695275] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] 1250258944 512-byte logical blocks: (640 GB/596 GiB)
[ 6909.696846] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] Write Protect is off
[ 6909.696863] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] Mode Sense: 17 00 10 08
[ 6909.698417] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] No Caching mode page found
[ 6909.698424] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 6909.703411] scsi_io_completion: 1 callbacks suppressed
[ 6909.703419] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 6909.703423] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] Sense Key : Data Protect [current] 
[ 6909.703428] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] Add. Sense: Logical unit access not authorized
[ 6909.703432] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 6909.703433] blk_update_request: 1 callbacks suppressed
[ 6909.703435] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sdd, sector 0
[ 6909.703439] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd, logical block 0, async page read
[ 6909.704014] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 6909.704020] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] Sense Key : Data Protect [current] 
[ 6909.704024] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] Add. Sense: Logical unit access not authorized
[ 6909.704028] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 6909.704031] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sdd, sector 0
[ 6909.704034] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd, logical block 0, async page read
[ 6909.704596] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 6909.704603] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] Sense Key : Data Protect [current] 
[ 6909.704607] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] Add. Sense: Logical unit access not authorized
[ 6909.704610] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 6909.704613] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sdd, sector 0
[ 6909.704616] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd, logical block 0, async page read
[ 6909.704630] ldm_validate_partition_table(): Disk read failed.
[ 6909.705046] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 6909.705050] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] Sense Key : Data Protect [current] 
[ 6909.705053] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] Add. Sense: Logical unit access not authorized
[ 6909.705056] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 6909.705058] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sdd, sector 0
[ 6909.705060] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd, logical block 0, async page read
[ 6909.705525] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 6909.705527] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] Sense Key : Data Protect [current] 
[ 6909.705533] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] Add. Sense: Logical unit access not authorized
[ 6909.705535] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 6909.705537] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sdd, sector 0
[ 6909.705539] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd, logical block 0, async page read
[ 6909.705986] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 6909.705989] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] Sense Key : Data Protect [current] 
[ 6909.705993] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] Add. Sense: Logical unit access not authorized
[ 6909.705995] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 6909.705997] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sdd, sector 0
[ 6909.705999] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd, logical block 0, async page read
[ 6909.706421] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 6909.706424] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] Sense Key : Data Protect [current] 
[ 6909.706427] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] Add. Sense: Logical unit access not authorized
[ 6909.706430] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 6909.706431] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sdd, sector 0
[ 6909.706433] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd, logical block 0, async page read
[ 6909.706442] Dev sdd: unable to read RDB block 0
[ 6909.706861] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 6909.706864] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] Sense Key : Data Protect [current] 
[ 6909.706867] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] Add. Sense: Logical unit access not authorized
[ 6909.706869] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 6909.706871] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sdd, sector 0
[ 6909.706873] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd, logical block 0, async page read
[ 6909.707296] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 6909.707299] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] Sense Key : Data Protect [current] 
[ 6909.707302] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] Add. Sense: Logical unit access not authorized
[ 6909.707305] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 6909.707307] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sdd, sector 0
[ 6909.707308] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd, logical block 0, async page read
[ 6909.707318]  sdd: unable to read partition table
[ 6909.711258] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] Attached SCSI disk
[ 6909.831440] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 6909.831449] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] Sense Key : Data Protect [current] 
[ 6909.831456] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] Add. Sense: Logical unit access not authorized
[ 6909.831461] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] CDB: Read(10) 28 00 4a 85 6f 80 00 00 08 00
[ 6909.831465] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sdd, sector 1250258816
[ 6909.831980] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd, logical block 156282352, async page read
[ 6908.519756] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[ 6908.684848] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=1058, idProduct=1021
[ 6908.684865] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 6908.684867] usb 1-2: Product: Ext HDD 1021
[ 6908.684870] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: Western Digital
[ 6908.684872] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: 574341554633333130333233
[ 6908.685583] usb-storage 1-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 6908.687976] scsi host13: usb-storage 1-2:1.0
[ 6909.694176] scsi 13:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WD       Ext HDD 1021     2021 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
[ 6909.695222] sd 13:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg4 type 0
[ 6909.695275] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] 1250258944 512-byte logical blocks: (640 GB/596 GiB)
[ 6909.696846] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] Write Protect is off
[ 6909.696863] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] Mode Sense: 17 00 10 08
[ 6909.698417] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] No Caching mode page found
[ 6909.698424] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 6909.703411] scsi_io_completion: 1 callbacks suppressed
[ 6909.703419] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 6909.703423] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] Sense Key : Data Protect [current] 
[ 6909.703428] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] Add. Sense: Logical unit access not authorized
[ 6909.703432] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 6909.703433] blk_update_request: 1 callbacks suppressed
[ 6909.703435] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sdd, sector 0
[ 6909.703439] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd, logical block 0, async page read
[ 6909.704014] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 6909.704020] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] Sense Key : Data Protect [current] 
[ 6909.704024] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] Add. Sense: Logical unit access not authorized
[ 6909.704028] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 6909.704031] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sdd, sector 0
[ 6909.704034] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd, logical block 0, async page read
[ 6909.704596] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 6909.704603] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] Sense Key : Data Protect [current] 
[ 6909.704607] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] Add. Sense: Logical unit access not authorized
[ 6909.704610] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 6909.704613] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sdd, sector 0
[ 6909.704616] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd, logical block 0, async page read
[ 6909.704630] ldm_validate_partition_table(): Disk read failed.
[ 6909.705046] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 6909.705050] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] Sense Key : Data Protect [current] 
[ 6909.705053] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] Add. Sense: Logical unit access not authorized
[ 6909.705056] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 6909.705058] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sdd, sector 0
[ 6909.705060] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd, logical block 0, async page read
[ 6909.705525] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 6909.705527] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] Sense Key : Data Protect [current] 
[ 6909.705533] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] Add. Sense: Logical unit access not authorized
[ 6909.705535] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 6909.705537] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sdd, sector 0
[ 6909.705539] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd, logical block 0, async page read
[ 6909.705986] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 6909.705989] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] Sense Key : Data Protect [current] 
[ 6909.705993] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] Add. Sense: Logical unit access not authorized
[ 6909.705995] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 6909.705997] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sdd, sector 0
[ 6909.705999] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd, logical block 0, async page read
[ 6909.706421] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 6909.706424] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] Sense Key : Data Protect [current] 
[ 6909.706427] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] Add. Sense: Logical unit access not authorized
[ 6909.706430] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 6909.706431] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sdd, sector 0
[ 6909.706433] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd, logical block 0, async page read
[ 6909.706442] Dev sdd: unable to read RDB block 0
[ 6909.706861] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 6909.706864] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] Sense Key : Data Protect [current] 
[ 6909.706867] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] Add. Sense: Logical unit access not authorized
[ 6909.706869] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 6909.706871] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sdd, sector 0
[ 6909.706873] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd, logical block 0, async page read
[ 6909.707296] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 6909.707299] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] Sense Key : Data Protect [current] 
[ 6909.707302] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] Add. Sense: Logical unit access not authorized
[ 6909.707305] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 6909.707307] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sdd, sector 0
[ 6909.707308] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd, logical block 0, async page read
[ 6909.707318]  sdd: unable to read partition table
[ 6909.711258] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] Attached SCSI disk
[ 6909.831440] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 6909.831449] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] Sense Key : Data Protect [current] 
[ 6909.831456] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] Add. Sense: Logical unit access not authorized
[ 6909.831461] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdd] CDB: Read(10) 28 00 4a 85 6f 80 00 00 08 00
[ 6909.831465] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sdd, sector 1250258816
[ 6909.831980] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd, logical block 156282352, async page read
```

I don't know if this is the right place to ask this question, but I am out of ideas. Is the drive itself dead? Is there any way to repair it to get access to the data on it? Any help or suggestions whatsoever are appreciated.

Comment: 'Buffer I/O error on dev sdd' not a good thing, if it does not mount at all it's dead. You can try to add the hdd as slave on another machine a see what happens.

Comment: Since it seems you can see it as a block device, if you have another large enough drive, from here you can try to use `ddrescue` or similar to copy off an image and see if you can recover data from that. Alternatively, you can send it to paid data recovery, which can be _expensive_ but is probably the most reliable. In either case, the drive is hosed and should be replaced.

Comment: @maniat1k I tried that already - no effect at all. But thanks for your help!
@TomHunt I will try `ddrescue`; I am afraid that this won't work, too ... I thought about sending the HDD to a paid recovery service, but the prices are horrendous. I have found an old backup of the data on the drive and I will live with it. After all: No backup, no pity

Answer (score 0):

Since data rescue is too expensive, I will live with the loss of data. I have not found a way to repair / restore the HDD to a working state.